# How to get or fetch button click event listener using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible in JavaScript or jQuery to get or fetch the `click` event listener of a button element? How?

For example the HTML,

```
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
```

and the jquery :

```
$("#btn1").on("click", function() {
     alert("Test");
});
```

and i want to do something like this.

```
// this is what i'm asking ( capture the click event of the button 1)
var f = $("#btn1").attr("onclick") --> undefined;

$("#btn1").on("click", function() {
     somefunction();
     f();

});
```

Comment: `buttonElement.addEventListener("click", function(clickEvent){ \* do something with your click event *\ });`

Comment: click "event" is an object which can be easily stored in any empty global json for future use .

Comment: @Roque please read the title, i want to capture the click event,  not adding it.

Comment: @esthrim I did. Before doing anything with the event, you need to listen for it. This is how you do it. The listener (the function) will receive the event. What you mean by "capturing" an event is unclear. But this is how you fetch it.

Comment: Oh. Actually what you want to fetch is not the event. The event is the object that is fired when a user click on an dom element. This event is then provided to the click listener: a function. If I understand you properly, this is this listener that you are trying to fetch.

Comment: If I am right, please edit your question with the proper terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onclick` property of your element to fetch the `onclick` listener (i.e. the code attached using the HTML node `onclick` property or with the `onclick` property of the corresponding DOM element).

```js
var button = document.querySelector("#the-button");
var onclick = button.onclick;
console.log(onclick);
onclick()
```

```html
<button id="the-button" onclick="alert('thing');">thing</button>
```

Listeners attached with `addEventListener` *cannot be fetched* by design.

Listeners attached with jQuery may be fetched. [You can have a look at this question for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-when-debugging-or-from-the-js-code#3426352) However I would strongly advise against doing this. It basically consists in hacking the library – i.e. accessing data you should not access to – and is highly inconsistent from a version to another.

Anyway, if you want to add additional behavior to the button without overwriting the previous behaviors, you do not need to save it. `addEventListener` or jQuery's `on` won't erase any previously attached listeners.

```js
var button = document.querySelector("#the-button");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert('something else');
});
```

```html
<button id="the-button" onclick="alert('thing');">thing</button>
```

Comment: is this the only way by using eval ?,

Comment: As far as I know, yes. the onclick attribute is only a string when you enter it in the HTML.

Comment: My bad! If you access it with `element.onclick` directly, you will have the function. Let me edit this question.

Comment: Avoiding `eval` is always wise.

Comment: i try your code but the button.onclick value is null, if you don't mind you can look at this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gukstk0y/

Comment: The on click attribute will only work with function added to the onclick attribute, either in-line in the element or with JS. Not with listeners. I would be surprised if you can fetch the listeners added with addEventListener or jqury's `on` (it would be a leak). Let me investigate this a bit further but it does not look like a good idea anyway FWIW.

Comment: i see..,Thank you for your effort.. if it is true than i must change the way it works..

Comment: Have a look at my edit for more information about fetching listeners attached with `addEventListener` or jQuery's `on`.